# How to sort data from backend service?

Tags: javascript, json, object

This is my data array :

```
[{
    "CodeDescription": "Spouse",
    "CodeID": "2",
    "CodeType": "HouseOwn",
    "ParentCodeID": "",
    "ParentType": ""
}, {
    "CodeDescription": "Parent",
    "CodeID": "3",
    "CodeType": "HouseOwn",
    "ParentCodeID": "",
    "ParentType": ""
}, {
    "CodeDescription": "AAA",
    "CodeID": "6",
    "CodeType": "City",
    "ParentCodeID": "",
    "ParentType": ""
}, {
    "CodeDescription": "Own",
    "CodeID": "1",
    "CodeType": "HouseOwn",
    "ParentCodeID": "",
    "ParentType": ""
}, {
    "CodeDescription": "BBB",
    "CodeID": "006",
    "CodeType": "Area",
    "ParentCodeID": "6",
    "ParentType": "City"
}, {
    "CodeDescription": "CCC",
    "CodeID": "Z01",
    "CodeType": "Area",
    "ParentCodeID": "6",
    "ParentType": "City"
}]
```

How do I get all `CodeDescription`'s of the objects where the `CodeType` has the value `"HouseOwn"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Do you literally mean sort, or do you mean you only want those codetypes?

Comment: Yes, I want sort all data and get all CodeDescription which its codeType is HouseOwn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter and map your data (used ES6 syntax):

```
let descriptions = data.filter(item => item.CodeType === "HouseOwn")
                       .map(item => item.CodeDescription);

console.log(descriptions); // Array [ "Spouse", "Parent", "Own" ]
```

ES5 analogy:

```
var descriptions = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item.CodeType === "HouseOwn";
}).map(function(item) {
    return item.CodeDescription;
});

console.log(descriptions); // Array [ "Spouse", "Parent", "Own" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
var codeDescriptionArray = theArrayofObjects
  .filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.codeType === "HouseOwn";
  })
  .map(function(obj) {
    return obj.codeDescription;
  });
```

This is an awesome tutorial that will help you practice sorting techniques using functional programming: http://reactivex.io/learnrx/